# Why does this program crashes?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;  
typedef struct {char *str;}String;
int main(){
    String name,add;
    cout<<"Name: ";
    cin>>name.str;
    cout<<"\n\tadd: ";
    cin>>add.str;
    cout<<"\n\tName:"<<name.str;
    cout<<"\n\t Add:"<<add.str;
    return 0;
}
```

Input is successful and then the program crashes.
Error displayed: stopped working

Comment: You should get [a couple of good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558). And learn about pointers. They don't just "magically" point somewhere valid, you have to *make* them point somewhere.

Comment: When you attached your debugger to it, and stepped through it line by line, where did it fail?

Comment: `str` points to some semi-random location, `std::cout` tries to write to that location, your operating system sees a rogue program trying to write to memory that doesn't belong to it and kills it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no, no, just use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)! Easier to use, and easier to understand!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;  

int main(){
    string name,add;
    cout<<"Name: ";
    getline(cin, name); // A name probably has more than 1 word
    cout<<"\n\tadd: ";
    cin>>add;
    cout<<"\n\tName:"<<name;
    cout<<"\n\t Add:"<<add;
    return 0;
}
```

As far as your problem goes with your original code, it is that you haven't allocated any memory for your `char*`, and are reading into memory that isn't yours.

Comment: my bad I used to code in turboc++ in the past because of outdated college and all and turboc++ didn't have anything like string. so thanks or putting some light on this

Answer (score 2):

`str` is a member of structure and its of `pointer` type and while doing `name.str;` it doesn't have any `valid memory` thats why it crashes at run time.

First allocate memory for `str` as

```
name.str = new char [SIZE]; /* SIZE is the no of bytes you want to allocate */
```

Once work is done free the memory by using `delete` to avoid memory leakage.

```
delete [] name.str;
```

Comment: *First allocate memory for str* -- and second...?  Aren't you forgetting the caveat of needing to call `delete []` to not leak memory?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes surely memory should be freed once job is done